# How to lower computational cost for a projectile speed variable?

Tags: javascript, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working with a friend of mine on a videogame project, that is currently under development in Unity 3D.
The game involves around a specific spawn point, that actually spawns objects as projectiles at a determined rate. Their speed is governed by public variables coded in a script (javascript) related to this spawn point.
The objects spawned search for the speed before they are thrown in the world, and then they travel at that determined speed, that may and will vary during the game(for this is one of the main features related to the human players' job in the game).

We are currently using this method to find the speed at which the projectile must travel:

```
var script: spawn = findObjectOfType(spawn);
myspeed = script.speed;
```

Now, doing this at every update could be very painful in terms of computational cost, as the update kicks in thousands of times per second. Is there any chance to achieve a better way to perform this operation?

I don't know if I have been clear enough, let me know if you need anything else and thank you for your patience!

Comment: Reading a variable is cheap and easy for the JIT to optimize. Benchmark your game and make sure this is really a problem before you spend time optimizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick note: I use C# for my unity work, so code may be slightly different, but the concepts still apply.

FindObjectOfType, GetComponent, etc. should be avoided at all costs within Update due to their slow performance.  There are many alternatives you could try depending on how the object is instantiated.  Since you didn't say in your question, I'll cover a few.

**If the "spawned" GameObject is already in the scene in the editor**
In this case, you can simply add a property to the script on the spawned object of type of the spawn point script.  Then, in the editor, drag the spawn point onto that object

**If you're using Instantiate to instantiate a prefab at runtime**
This is actually not a good idea if you're instantiating a lot of objects.  Object instantiation is a very expensive operation.  If possible, you should store your instantiated objects and just reuse them.  Either way, if this is your approach, you could use GetComponent on the instantiated prefab to get a reference to the spawned object's script, and then set the value you need from there.  This still involves using GetComponent in Update, but that is still somewhat better than using FindObjectOfType

**A completely different approach: Particle Systems**
An alternative to all this scripting nonsense is to just use a particle system attached to the spawn point.  Particle Systems are designed to create large numbers of objects very quickly and efficiently.  Once creating the particle system, you can just set the starting velocity in the editor

**Some other notes that may be helpful:**
You said in your question that Update happens "thousands of times per second".  Update runs (as the so very helpful default comment says) every frame.  This means that the time between updates can vary wildly from computer to computer and even moment to moment.  This also means that code written in Update is, by default, framerate-dependent.  If you are spawning these objects for gameplay reasons, you need to be sure their spawn rate doesn't depend on framerate.  You can use Time.DeltaTime to get the number of seconds since the last Update.  For example (sorry about the C#, but you should be able to translate easily):

```
public float TimeBetweenActions = 1f;
private float elapsed = 0f;

void Update() {
    elapsed += Time.DeltaTime;
    if(elapsed >= TimeBetweenActions){
        DoTheThing();
        elapsed-=TimeBetweenActions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a reference of 'script' in the Start method.

Then you work on it in the Update. Also: is better to set up a tag for the 'spawn' and use 'gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string tag);'

Last thing: if you're really worried about speed... Just don't use JavaScript

Comment: It is not "Better" to set up a tag and use findgameobjectwithtag. any Find method is slow. 
Last thing. It doesn't matter if he uses JavaScript. It will all be converted to MonoBehaviour. Using JavaScript in Unity3d `Does not Compromise Speed`